# Why can sqlAlchemy return partial queries without them being explicitly defined?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following definition as per the sqlalchemy ORM DeclarativeBase examples.

```py
class ImageMetadata(Base):
    __tablename__ = "image_metadata"
    main_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    secondary_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    mission_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    sensing_time: Mapped[DateTime] = mapped_column(DateTime)
    cloud_cover: Mapped[Optional[float]]
    north_lat: Mapped[float]
    south_lat: Mapped[float]
    west_lon: Mapped[float]
    east_lon: Mapped[float]
    base_url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(120))
    status: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    images: Mapped[Optional[List["BandMetadata"]]] = relationship(back_populates="band_metadata",
                                                                  cascade="all, delete-orphan", default_factory=list)
    dataset_images: Mapped[Optional[List["DatasetImages"]]] = relationship(backref="dataset_images",
                                                                           cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                                                                           default_factory=list)
    added_timestamp: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(default_factory=datetime.datetime.now)


class BandMetadata(Base):
    __tablename__ = "band_metadata"
    image_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    main_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("image_metadata.main_id"), primary_key=True)
    image_url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(120))
    band_metadata: Mapped["ImageMetadata"] = relationship(back_populates="images")
    added_timestamp: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(default_factory=datetime.datetime.now)


class DatasetImages(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dataset_images"
    dataset_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    main_id: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("image_metadata.main_id"))
    composite_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    status: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
```

It's been working great up until the moment I queried the DatasetImages:

```py
for x in session.query(DatasetImages).all():
    print(x)
```

returns all hits for a single composite type ('ir').

```
(DatasetImages(dataset_id='LC08_L1GT_025047_20151026_20170225_01_T2', main_id='LC80250472015299LGN01', composite_type='ir', status='available'),)
(DatasetImages(dataset_id='LC08_L1GT_025047_20151026_20170225_01_T2', main_id='LC80250472015299LGN01', composite_type='ir', status='available'),)
(DatasetImages(dataset_id='LC08_L1GT_025047_20160302_20170224_01_T2', main_id='LC80250472016062LGN01', composite_type='ir', status='available'),)
...
(DatasetImages(dataset_id='LC08_L1GT_025047_20170929_20171013_01_T2', main_id='LC80250472017272LGN00', composite_type='ir', status='available'),)
```

I've tried some debugging like:

```py
stmt = select(DatasetImages)
print(stmt)
for reslt in session.execute(stmt):
      print(reslt)
```

and get a statement that looks useful:

```sql
SELECT dataset_images.dataset_id, dataset_images.main_id, dataset_images.composite_type, dataset_images.status
FROM dataset_images
```

If run separately I get back all results for both currently available composite_types. However on my script, the results I get back from `session.execute(stmt)` throw back only results of 'ir' composite_types.

If I explicitly query other composite types I get them back:

```py
for x in session.query(DatasetImages).where(DatasetImages.composite_type == 'rgb').where(DatasetImages.status == 'available'):
      print(x)
```

like so:

```
DatasetImages(dataset_id='T14QNG_20230521T165849', main_id='L1C_T14QNG_A032413_20230521T171555', composite_type='rgb', status='available')
DatasetImages(dataset_id='T14QNG_20230526T165901', main_id='L1C_T14QNG_A041393_20230526T170604', composite_type='rgb', status='available')
DatasetImages(dataset_id='T14QNG_20230531T165849', main_id='L1C_T14QNG_A032556_20230531T171619', composite_type='rgb', status='available')
...
DatasetImages(dataset_id='T14QNG_20230615T165901', main_id='L1C_T14QNG_A041679_20230615T171239', composite_type='rgb', status='available')
```

I'm guessing it might be related to the backref relationship as defined in the ImageMetadata class, however back_populates definition was raising errors and I don't fully understand how back populating or back referencing another table can cause a difference in results when the sql query generated by sqlalchemy itself looks alright.

I'm running Python 3.11, SQLAlchemy 2.0.16 on Windows 11

Any ideas of why this might be happening?
I can think of a couple of ways to work around this, but I don't feel comfortable implementing a workaround when I don't understand why the straightforward solution is failing.
Thanks!

Comment: what does `for x in session.query(sqlachemy.func.distinct(DatasetImages.composite_type)).all()` return?

Comment: @python_user returns both currently available composite_types in the table:
`('ir',)('rgb',)`

Comment: if that returns all of your current `composite_types` then I do not see why the query without distinct would filter out rows

Comment: @python_user that's exactly my issue. I don't understand why if not explicitly called for the other types using a WHERE statement, SQLAlchemy is returning only one single type of composite_type. I guess I'll raise an issue in github to see what the devs think about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [posted as a Discussion on SQLAlchemy github](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9995) where the answer to the issue was resolved.

According to the answer there: "ORM queries uniquely on primary key since that's how the identity map is populated."

So each table registry must have a unique primary key value in order for ORM to return all results, otherwise, duplicates are excluded from the results.

To fix this, the DatasetImage must have another unique field that is defined as the primary key, for example the composite_type:

```py
class DatasetImages(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dataset_images"
    dataset_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    main_id: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("image_metadata.main_id"))
    composite_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    status: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
```